# Repositories added for "Maya" not "Precise"

Tags: repository, add-apt-repository

I wanted to test Cinnamon in my Xubuntu 12.04. After installing it, when I try to add a PPA it is added for "maya" not "precise". I purged Cinnamon PPA but it is still the same... what can I do about it?

PS poking around I guess I should edit  /etc/lsb-release but could anyone post its default content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have used the Cinnamon ppa for Precise available at [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~gwendal-lebihan-dev/+archive/cinnamon-stable), rather than the Mint repositories, it shouldn't have altered your LSB information, although I reproduce the 12.04 LSB information further below.*

The useful program, `ppa-purge`, is in the repositories for 12.04, but you have probably tried that, but it is useful as it removes all the ppa's files and dependencies and not just the ppa's list.

I assume your main `/etc/apt/sources.list` is functioning and you have checked that no references to Maya have crept in there and that there are no remnants of the Cinnamon ppa left in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Nevertheless, if you suspect your `sources.list` has been contaminated, you could run

```
sudo sed -i 's/maya/precise/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

which would substitute any references to Maya with precise, and was useful in this different case at [Ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1970716).

*However, for your reference, this is the output of `/etc/lsb-release` for Xubuntu 12.04.1

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS"
```

If you were running the original 12.04 and haven't upgraded to the point release, 12.04.1, instead use `"Ubuntu 12.04 LTS"` and not `"Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS"` in the final category.

Comment: Thank you very much Mik. Actually I used Launchpad PPA, but I'm also using a Mint repo, as I couldn't find any other with xfapplet 4.10. BTW I used purge but that didn't help. Thanks for posting the content of the file.